# when loading a binary file the current data gets lost

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, dynamic

Some of the code is provided by my teacher due to corona outbreak and he doesnt answer emails I am stuck.

The code he provided was this

```
printf("Removing old data in array...");                
free(myCities);                                 
myCities = readFromBinFile(&nrOfCitiesAdded);    
...

struct city *readFromBinFile(int *nrOfCities){    
    struct city *temp = NULL; 
    FILE *fp = fopen("/Users/cul01/Desktop/minTextFil","rb"); 
    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("Could not open file\n");    
    else {
        printf("Reading from file...\n");       
        fread(nrOfCities, sizeof(int), 1, fp);       
        temp = (struct city*)calloc(*nrOfCities, sizeof(struct city));       
        if(temp == NULL)             
            printf("Error allocating memory");        
        else           
            fread(temp, sizeof(struct city), *nrOfCities, fp);
    }   
    fclose(fp); 
    return temp; 
}
```

Now everything works as it should but when I add a city and then try to load a file that doesnt exist and then add another city, and print it out I get stuff like this `9e   10267    iles\Common manch`, but the other city is fine it is just the first one that get stuck. If more code is needed I am happy to provide it.

Comment: You should not call `fclose(fp);` if opening the file failed. That line should be in the `else` block.

Comment: The caller needs to check if `myCities` is `NULL` before trying to print it.

Comment: I understood the first one but what do you mean print it

Comment: You said you're seing garbage when you try to print a city. You shouldn't try to print anything if the function returns `NULL` because it couldn't open the file.

Comment: Yeah, but lets say that I am creating a city and in the middle of the process loaded a file that doesnt exist, I want it to save my old city that was in there. Currently if I create a city and then load a file that doesnt exist that city doesnt get saved at all and it because like that `9e   10267    iles\Common manch`

Comment: There's nothing in the question about saving cities. It's just loading all the cities from a file.

Comment: Dont mean like saving "saving" more of that I dont want the data to get lost

Comment: Do you want to append the cities read from the file to the existing array in `myCities`?

Comment: is there a place we can chat more because it seems like stack doesnt like long comments field

Comment: SE has chat rooms, but you don't have enough rep to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Call `readFromBinFile()` before freeing `myCities`. If it returns `NULL`, keep the old value.

```
int tempCitiesAdded;
struct city *citiesTemp = readFromBinFile(&tempCitiesAdded);
if (citiesTemp) {
    free(myCities);
    myCities = citiesTemp;
    nrOfCitiesAdded = tempCitiesAdded;
}
```